# How to do signin test automation framework.

Tags: selenium, frameworks

I want to learn the sign in test by using clicking on the sign in button and the text will appear like my name, password and it will automatically sign in.

I am using it these way

```
@FindBy (xpath = "//div[@class='footer-menu-list ']//a[@href='/employer']")
public static WebElement medicareMenu;
```

Then the method I created:

```
    public void checkmedicareMenu() {
    medicareMenu.click();

}
```

Then my testcase:

```
@Test
public void testmedicareMenu() {
    welcome.checkmedicareMenu();

}
```

Comment: can you be more specific on your question like what do you want exactly? When you say you want to learn is that you are stuck on something or asking whether your approach is right ?

Comment: What I am trying to say when I run my test and when the browser pops up it will automatically click on the sign in button and then and automatically write my username or email and password and again automatically sign in to my homepage

Comment: ok..if we assume this is your current behaviour, is that you want some thing like you need to enter the details against automatic login?

Comment: Its better if I post my full codes. That way you will be able to understand better.